# What value ranges are supported by major datetime libraries?

Tags: date, datetime, time, api-design

I'm looking for an overview of the internal data representation and earliest/latest dates supported by typical time libraries in different programming languages.

I can remember reading a webpage about that a while back but can't find it any more after dozens of Google search term refinements.

Comment: According to our [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) guidance, "**Some questions are still off-topic, even if they fit into one of the categories listed above:**...Questions asking us to *recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource* are off-topic..."

Comment: I guess the description was not clear about it, I tried to rephrase. I'm not looking to find an off-site resource.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see the code of all major libs to be sure about that, but I guess many of them store data as fields, with most of them being numbers, such as year, month, day, hour, minute, etc.

The limits are either the upper/lower bounds of the respective numerical types, or some artificial value (such as "year 1 million" to represent a "very far future").

I think it also depends on the types being represented:

- If the type represents only a local date (day/month/year, without hours and no timezone/offset), then the limits should be the upper/lower bounds of the type used to store the year value, or some artificial value.
- If the type represents a timestamp (number of seconds/milliseconds/whatever-precision-of-seconds-the-API-supports since unix epoch), the limit can be the maximum value of the type used to store this value, or some artificial limit value.

And so on. But each of the cases above might give you a different limit, and the consistency between limits from different types will depend on the API.

Is that what you're asking?

---

Some API's, such as in Java, has documented limits for each type:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#MIN
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#MIN

And note how the limit is different for each type.

Comment: Not exactly. I'm familiar with the general concept and typical epoch, min and max values.  I'd like to get actual data, like Java 8 Date-Time API has a range from `-999999999-01-01T00:00:00` to `+999999999-12-31T23:59:59.999999999` etc.

Comment: Look at the 2 javadoc links above, note that each type has different limit values. I put just 2, but take a look at the java.time package to see all the types and their respective limits. In this case, I agree with nubz, that you can solve this by looking at the API, for the libs that have this information available in the docs - and for the others, the only way is to get the source code.